# From for loops to numpy dot implementation

Tags: python, loops, numpy

```
N=100 

reliab=zeros((N,N))


for i in range(N):    

    for j in range(N):
        if random() < 0.6:
            reliab[i,j] = 1
        else:
            reliab[i,j] = 0
```

As in my code this matrix filling is recalled a huge number of times, these for loops should be changed with a dot product...but I dunno how to do it...
Anyone willing to help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your problem completely, but the following line should be doing the same thing as your code:

```
reliab = numpy.int32(numpy.random.rand(N,N) < 0.6)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> reliab = np.random.random((N,N))
>>> reliab = reliab < 0.6
>>> reliab.dtype = np.int8
>>> reliab
array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, ..., 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, ..., 1, 0, 1],
       ..., 
       [0, 1, 0, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int8)
```

Comment: Nice. You should probably scale the reliab before changing its type. OP wants to assign 1 with a probability of 0.6.

Comment: @Amaç Herdağdelen: np.random.random is on the interval `[0,1)`, so scaling is not necessary.  (Or summing my array, I get 6009 out of 10000, which is pretty much spot on for 60%).  (Yes you did beat me to the answer and they are similar, but I figured i'd finish writing the answer anyway).

Comment: Sorry, I saw an earlier version of your answer which didn't include the "< 0.6" comparison. There's nothing wrong right now.